# Split a comma delimited string to a table in BIRT

Tags: eclipse, report, reporting, birt

I'm creating a BIRT report and I need to split a comma delimited string from a dataset into multiple columns in a table.

The data looks like:

> 256,1400.031,-70.014,1,4.544,0.36,10,31,30.89999962,0
>
> 256,1400,-69.984,2,4.574,1.36,10,0,0,0
>
> ...

The data is stored this way in the database and I can't change it but I need to be able to display it as a table. I'm new to BIRT, any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

I think the easiest way is to create a computed column in the dataset for each field. 
For example if the merged field from database is named "mergedData" you can split it with this kind of expression:

First field (computed column) expression:

```
var tempArray=row["mergedData"].split(",");
tempArray[0];
```

Second field:

```
var tempArray=row["mergedData"].split(",");
tempArray[1];
```

etc..

Comment: I tried something similar to that, but how many objects in the delimited list is variable.

Comment: But how do we know what each column represents, if the list is variable? Also, is there a max number of columns or is it completely generic?

Comment: There's another field that saves column header labels (also in comma delimited list) that corresponds to the data. But both of these columns can have completely variable length.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on some variables that you did not mention.

If the dataset is stagenent (*not updated much or ever*).  Open the data set with Excel, converiting it from .csv to .xls and save.

Use the Excel as a datasource. Assuming you are using BIRT 4.1 or newer this should work fine.

I don't think there is any SQL code that easily converts .csv